# How to create and access multiple objects based on user input - C++

Tags: c++, object, user-input

```
int main()
{
    string name, sound, owner;
    int age;
    int answer = 1;
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        ++i;
        puts("Enter the dog info below");
        puts("Dog's name: ");
        cin >> name;
        puts("Dog's sound: ");
        cin >> sound;
        puts("Dog's age: ");
        cin >> age;
        puts("Dog's owner: ");
        cin >> owner;

        puts("Do you want to add one more dogs to the database?\n1: Yes\n0:     No");
        cin >> answer;

        Dog name(name, sound, age, owner);

    } while (answer != 0);

    for (int a = i; i > 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%s", name.getname().c_str());
        printf("\n\n%s is a dog who is %d years old, says %s and %s the owner\n\n",
            name.getname().c_str(), name.getage(), name.getsound().c_str(), name.getowner().c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the simple code for creating several objects based on input by the user. I have classes and methods set up. It works just fine without the do while loop. But I cant create the objects based on the users input and print them. The following line show error "has no member getname." and same error for every method called. I understand why this is happening but is there any solution to this?

```
name.getname().c_str(), name.getage(), name.getsound().c_str(), name.getowner().c_str());
```

Comment: Show us your `Dog` class.

Comment: "I understand why this is happening" - would you mind explaining why it's happening to help gauge your knowledge level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues.

First: You declared two variables with the same name in different scopes: `string name` in the `main()` scope and `Dog name` in the `do ... while` scope. The `Dog` object only exists inside the `do ... while` loop. When you try to access it outside the loop, you get the error `... has no member getname` because you're actually accessing a `string` object, not a `Dog` object.

Second: You're not storing the `Dog`s information that the user enters.

You need to use a vector to store the `Dog` objects:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    string name, sound, owner;
    int age;
    int answer = 1;
    std::vector<Dog> dogs; // Vector to store Dog objects

    do
    {
        puts("Enter the dog info below");
        puts("Dog's name: ");
        cin >> name;
        puts("Dog's sound: ");
        cin >> sound;
        puts("Dog's age: ");
        cin >> age;
        puts("Dog's owner: ");
        cin >> owner;

        puts("Do you want to add one more dogs to the database?\n1: Yes\n0:     No");
        cin >> answer;

        Dog dog(name, sound, age, owner);
        dogs.push_back(dog); // store current dog's info

    } while (answer != 0);

    for (int a = 0; a < dogs.size(); a++)
    {
        Dog& dog = dogs.at(a); // Get the dog at position i

        printf("%s", dog.getname().c_str());
        printf("\n\n%s is a dog who is %d years old, says %s and %s the owner\n\n",
            dog.getname().c_str(), dog.getage(), dog.getsound().c_str(), dog.getowner().c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```